# A quick cheatsheet on using a bit map to store multiple values

Tags: bit-manipulation

I always get confused when I am about to use a bit map to store multiple flags. For example, if there are 10 possible properties for an object (all Yes or No), I use an unsigned int and the first 10 bits (from LSB) based on the properties. Now how to set and unset a particular bit and also how to check if a bit is set or not?

If I want to unset the 5th bit, I use:
bitand (flag, 2^5 - 1)

But I am not clear on what to use to check if 5th bit is set or not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

check if the n<sup>th</sup> bit is set:

```
(flags & (1 << n)) != 0
```

set the n<sup>th</sup> bit:

```
flags |= (1 << n)
```

clear the n<sup>th</sup> bit:

```
flags &= ~(1 << n)
```

toggle the n<sup>th</sup> bit:

```
flags ^= (1 << n)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed, will paste it on my desk :)